# object released without pool- just leaking?

Tags: objective-c

object release without pool-just leaking?
Is this memory leak?
How can i avoid this?

Comment: Your question is really too general. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question you asked, what, 24 hours ago? I would suggest strongly that you go read the "Cocoa Memory Management" documentation. Plug that into google and it is the first link.

Answer (score 2):

The object isn't being released, it's being *autoreleased*. Autorelease is like deferred cleanup, it means "I'm done with this, feel free to get rid of it later". Sometimes another part of the code, like a function that yours was called from, will pick up the object (*retain* it) before the autorelease occurs.

Autoreleasing is managed by a class called `NSAutoreleasePool`. The class maintains a stack of pools, and when an object is autoreleased, it is added to the topmost pool on the stack. Draining a pool causes it to release all of the objects that have been added to it - and if any have been released enough, they will be deallocated. You don't need to manage the `NSAutoreleasePool` instances directly if you don't want to; you can just put your code into an `@autoreleasepool{}` block and the compiler will insert a static `NSAutoreleasePool` instance.

There are three approaches you can take to remove this message. One, which works on both the Mac and iPhone, is the one suggested by KennyTM - add an autorelease pool around you code that uses autoreleased objects. You need one for each thread where you autorelease Cocoa objects, more is possible but usually one is sufficient. The second alternative, though only if you're targeting Mac OS, is to enable garbage collection. That won't solve all of your problems but does mean that unreferenced objects are automatically removed.

On both platforms you can also use Automatic Reference Counting, which instructs the compiler to take care of memory management for you. You still need to put the autorelease pools in place, and there are some "interesting" interactions with toll-free bridging, but on the whole if you're struggling with reference counting it's probably best to automate it.

If you're not familiar with retain counts and autorelease pools, you may have other memory management problems in your code. I recommend you use the static analyser on your project (choose "Build & Analyze" from Xcode's build menu) and address any issues it raises.

Comment: And now there's also AppCode, which has a pretty decent static analyzer as well. If nothing else, that it has.

Answer (score 1):

> is this memory leak???

Yes.

> if yes how can i avoid this???

You need an `NSAutoreleasePool`. For example,

```
int main () {
  NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  ... your main code ...

  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Im call various functions in the main?? should i create different pools for each function??? or one pool in the main will do???

Comment: One pool is enough. (Unless you want to release some memory fast.)

Comment: Keep in mind, that `NSApplicationMain` creates an autorelease pool for you.

Comment: im new to cocoa?

nsapplicationmain creates autorelease pool, so do all the variables i use in the "-awakefornib" and -Event handling functions will be autoreleased???

In my main() im creating a object of "Class A" in which im calling nsapplicationmain().

And im also createing a thread in the "Class A" (class created in the main)...

Comment: You are doing it wrong (no worries, we were all new at one time or another);  you shouldn't be creating threads by hand and the need to create objects in main() is an advanced patterns.  I suggest you step back from StackOverflow and focus your time on the Objective-C, Cocoa, and Memory Management Guides offered at http://developer.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you see this message logged before your main function is called, it's because static initializers are creating temp variables that are being autoreleased with no pool.

Here's a solution (I put it just above my main function).  The AppInitFunc is called before C++ static initializers, so the pool is created before, well, static initializers are called.

```
static NSAutoreleasePool* cplusplus_static_pool = nil;
extern void AppInitFunc(void) __attribute__ ((constructor));
void AppInitFunc(void)
{
    cplusplus_static_pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
}

extern void AppTermFunc(void) __attribute__ ((destructor));
void AppTermFunc(void)
{
//  draining pool here may cause a crash on termination.
//  [cplusplus_static_pool drain];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* release the static init pool, create another */ 
    [cplusplus_static_pool release]; 
    cplusplus_static_pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}

/* now you can do this and not leak */    
static const NSArray* kArrayOfStrings = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil] retain];
```